# Compatibility Problem after Update from Xamarin.Forms to .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, upgrade, nuget-package

In Visual Studio 2022 I developped a Xamarin.Forms solution that compiles and runs on Android and UWP (Windows). I used Microsoft's Upgrade Assistant to upgrade to .Net 8.0 and .Net MAUI. This results in 4 errors for the UWP project (German version of VS):

```
Fehler  NU1202  Das Paket System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0 ist nicht mit net8.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)/win10-x64 kompatibel. Paket System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0 unterstützt Folgendes: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)
```

That means: packet `System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0` is not compatible with  `net8.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)`.

Packet `System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0` supports `uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)`.

Any ideas what to do?

**Edit:**
This is my project file after applying the upgrade assistant:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <TemplateGuid>{98C37F10-6541-44BE-B1E6-7EB3EB8C08F1}</TemplateGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>BeMoSoft.Packer.UWP</RootNamespace>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>true</EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseMaui>True</UseMaui>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="icon_backup.png" />
    <Content Include="icon_journeys.png" />
    <Content Include="icon_settings.png" />
    <Content Include="icon_task.png" />
    <Content Include="icon_journey.png" />
    <Content Include="icon_templates.png" />
    <Content Include="packer_logo.png" />
    <Content Include="Properties\Default.rd.xml" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LargeTile.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LargeTile.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LargeTile.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SmallTile.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SmallTile.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SmallTile.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-16.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-256.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-48.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-16.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-256.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="xamarin_logo.png" />
    <Content Include="icon_about.png" />
    <Content Include="icon_feed.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Packer\Packer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UpdateClient\UpdateClient.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|ARM'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Test\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Test\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Test\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.5.240311000" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="8.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I had a similar experience and finally gave up. I ported the code over one MVVM module at a time. It was somewhat time consuming but in the end I had a working application with a whole new set of problems. Conceptually Maui is far more advanced than Xamarin, and there are a lot of code minimization time savers, but it shows up in the form of poor performance. Things I was doing in Xamarin are impossible in Maui. I needed to rethink entire layouts and behaviors, and opt for a (IMHO) poorer quality design to combat performance lags. Additionally, the finished project was twice the size on disk.

Comment: Please show your project file. I suspect you have some outdated references in there. The upgrade assistant is not perfect.

Comment: See my project file in Edit

Comment: I have tried to add the `System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0` package in the new .net 8.0 maui project without this error. You can try to clean an rebuild or adding this package after migration completed.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT: With these changes I get the same errors...

Comment: @stewbash: Thank you for your evaluation. As I am programming just for my personal fun, I'll skip migration to Net Maui and keep my project with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: The default .net 8 maui project refer to `Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK 1.3.230724000` and `Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D 1.0.5.1`. You can try to use the two old version instead of the last version.